# Pre-commit build tools for Perforce

Tags: msbuild, perforce, pre-commit

Are there any tools available to run pre-commit builds for Perforce and auto submit changes on successful execution?

I'm looking for a server side solution (unlike JetBrains teamcity VS addin which does it from client + has some others limitations like inability to add a job id) which can also queue up multiple check-ins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Electric Commander has a pre-flight capability.  Might be worth a look.  Otherwise you can use a change-content trigger to intercept a commit, invoke a build process with the changed files,
and then approve or reject the submit.

Answer (score 0):

We use [ProofBuild](http://wiki.pmease.com/display/qb2/Working+with+Proof+Build). I use it in a specific configuration that doesn't do automatic check-in (only checks that the changelist is good), but ProofBuild supports this automation too.